# Increment a counter from insider ender

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to keep a counter that is incremented inside my render function. In the past I would modify this.props.counter inside render, which I know is wrong.

Setting the this.state.counter 100+ times inside the render function doesn't seem right either.

How/where should I store this counter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it simply as property of the component you are rendering (javascript object property: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_properties.asp not react props). Simply `this.counter=0` in componentDidMount() and `this.counter += 1` in render should do the trick.